# Getting jQuery code to run inside a modal

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

I'm trying to doing some simple jQuery stuff inside a modal and can't figure out how to call the code so it works inside the modal. I assume the problem is that the modal exists after the page has been loaded.

Here is my CoffeeScript:

```
jQuery ->
  $(".alter_workout").click (e) ->
    url = $(@).attr("href")
    dialog_form = $("<div id=\"dialog-form\" title=\"Edit Workout\">Loading form...</div>").dialog(
      modal: true
      autoOpen: false
      closeText: "close"
      closeOnEscape: true
      hide: "fade"
      show: "fade"
      width: 550
      dialogClass: "admin_forms"
      open: ->
        $(@).load url + " #content"
      close: ->
        $("#dialog-form").remove()
    )
    dialog_form.dialog "open"
    e.preventDefault()

jQuery ->
  $('form').on 'click', '.remove_fields', (event) ->
    $(this).prev('input[type=hidden]').val('1')
    $(this).closest('fieldset').fadeOut()
    event.preventDefault()

  $('form').on 'click', '.add_fields', (event) ->
    time = new Date().getTime()
    regexp = new RegExp($(this).data('id'), 'g')
    $(this).before($(this).data('fields').replace(regexp, time))
    event.preventDefault()
```

The first `jQuery ->` is the part that loads the modal. The second `jQuery ->` is the jQuery that is supposed to be executed inside the modal.

Any ideas? I can't even get an error message out of this, so I'm totally lost. When I click one of the `.remove_fields` links it just jumps to the top of the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it turns out the correct answer was much simpler than expected. All I had to do is replace

```
 $('form').on 'click', '.remove_fields', (event) ->
```

with

```
 $(document).on 'click', '.remove_fields', (event) ->
```

Since the form didn't exist when I load the page, the JS code couldn't find it. The solution is to search the document for the selector `.remove_fields`

Problem solved!

Answer (score 3):

i think you could try working your js when a modal event hapen.
for example the bootsrap modal has some nice options about events in modals
like:

```
 $('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
      // do something…
    });
```

the `'shown.bs.modal'` is the event when the modal is shown in the user screen, so you can execute all your js inside this event.
i tried it and works fine. 
i guess the problem whit modals is that they load only when you call it so you never will be able to execute js on a document.ready function, or a js in the end of the body.

sorry about my english

Comment: It turns out the answer is actually much simpler. You just have to replace ('#myModal') with (document).

Comment: if you use more than one modal in the same page you are gona be in truble, its better to execute the actions you want for the modal in question, except you want to do the same function in all the modals in your page. in that case its better to select the document, as you say

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the listeners that you want to be available in the modal are called before the modal is opened, so those elements aren't there when the bottom "on" functions are called. Maybe you could bundle those two in a separate function and call that function when ".alter_workout" is called.

Sorry I'm not confident with coffeescript to do that, but here's an example in straight javascript (I only included one of the listener functions), but hopefully this makes sense:

```
$(".alter_workout").click(function(e) {
    //open modal stuff
    //call listener functions here, once the modal is opened and elements are displayed
    $('form').on('click', 'add_fields', function(event){
        time = new Date().getTime();
        regexp = new RegExp($(this).data('id'), 'g');
        $(this).before($(this).data('fields').replace(regexp, time));
        event.preventDefault();
    });
    ///other listener function as well

});
```

Comment: I'm having a bit of trouble figuring out where I should put the JS that executes inside the modal. Can I just stick it inside the modal code, dialog_form.dialog "open"?

Comment: so from what I can tell, dialog_form.dialog "open" opens up the modal with settings you prescribed, correct? If that is so, then you want to call the listeners _after_ the modal opens, so you would call those two functions (the "on - click" listeners) on the following lines. Does that make sense?

Comment: Sort of. I've tried moving it around a few different places, and can't seem to get it to work. I'll keep trying different things.

Comment: to debug you might add some simpler listeners with logs to check where the error is. Using on can be a real pain sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

At a glance, it appears that it doesn't add the click handlers to the form because it doesn't find a form to add handlers to. What you might want to do is move the `$('form').on 'click'` handler definitions to a function and then invoke that function following the creation of the modal dialog on-screen.

Comment: Can you give me an example of how to do that? Sorry. I'm pretty new to javascript.